# Using FragmentScenario with nested NavHostFragments makes certain navigations impossible to verify during testing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-fragmentscenario

In my app I have a MainActivity that holds a NavHostFragment. That NavHostFragment is used to display Fragments, some of which have their own NavHostFragments.

For example, MainActivity hold NavHostFragment1 which points to main_nav_graph.xml which displays FragmentA by default. The user interacts with Fragment A to launch MasterDetailFragment which contains NavHostFragment2.

So the main_nav_graph.xml looks like: FragmentA -> MasterDetailFragment

When the user is in MasterDetailFragment and clicks the back button, we intercept the back press and show the user a CancelConfirmationFragment. If the user confirms that they want to leave the screen, then we need to perform a navigation back to FragmentA. This is where it gets a little tricky.

If I just blindly use the findNavController() function from CancelConfirmationFragment then it will get a handle to the nested NavHostFragment (NavHostFragment2) and attempt to perform a navigation with that, which will be incorrect. What I really need is to get a handle to the NavHostFragment1 in MainActivity. To do this, I've created an interface that MainActivity implements that returns MainActivity's NavHostFragment when called.

```
// This gets a handle to MainActivity's navController
(requireActivity() as HasNavController).getNavController().popBackStack(R.id.fragment_a, false)
```

When I manually test my app, this works great. However, when I run Instrumentation tests on MasterDetailFragment in isolation, I run into an issue because I don't actually have an instance of MainActivity holding my MasterDetailFragment, I have an instance of the Activity that FragmentScenario creates which does not implement my special interface.

To get my instrumentation tests working, I stop using FragmentScenario and create an Activity specifically for the test called FakeMainActivity. FakeMainActivity would have a NavHostFragment and would implement the special interface that MainActivity implements. In the test setup I could then pass a mock nav controller to FakeMainActivity and verify that when the user confirms they want to navigate back that the mock nav controller has a certain call made on it. This seems like an OK solution, however, I feel like I could pass in any navigation destination (even one that is impossible to reach) and the test would pass, but in reality it would not so I'm not even sure if the test is really worth writing.

Am I fundamentally using either Navigation Components or FragmentScenario incorrectly?

Is this just a tricky thing to test in general?

Should I just be testing navigations like this (moving from one nav host to another) in a non-isolated test like an e2e test or integration test between two fragments?

Would it make sense if FragmentScenario could accept an argument that allows a custom Activity to be launched by it instead of the Activity that FragmentScenario supplies?

Comment: Why not just use `requireParentFragment().findNavController()`?

Comment: In the case of my CancelConfirmationFragment, it is on the graph pointed at by my second NavHostController. So in CancelConfimationFragment if I have a click listener listening for the user to click the positive button, and I call requireParentFragment().findNavController(), won't that return the controller for my second nav host fragment?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I guess what I'm realizing is that when you have multiple nav controllers, there isn't a foolproof way to get a handle to the desired nav controller from any fragment in the graph(s). Assuming you have a single activity app, calling requireActivity(), casting it then calling getNavController works. Calling requireParentActivity().findNavContoller() can work, but only if the fragment you call it has a parent that contains the correct nav controller which won't always be the case.